# COUNT the number of columns where a condition is true? SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that looks something like

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1  3     5    3    3
```

What I want to do is COUNT the number of `3`s in this particular row.

I have tried the

```
select COUNT(*) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'   -- but obviously I need WHERE Col1 = 3 OR Col2 = 3...
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It's a sign of a broken design - if you have data items that are in some sense the same "type" of thing, such that you want to query across all of those values, they ought to all be contained in a single column. This table ought to have 3 columns `(ID, <X>, Col)` where `<X>` is an appropriate name for whatever the *data* item is that's been embedded in the *name* of those 4 columns as trailing numbers, and then you'd have 4 *rows* - `(1,1,3)`, `(1,2,5)`, `(1,3,3)` and `(1,4,3)`. The query is then trivial to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what OP asked, this can be done

```
select 
CASE WHEN Col1 = 3 then 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Col2 = 3 then 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Col3 = 3 then 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN Col4 = 3 then 1 ELSE 0 END
From TableName
```

Comment: Simple and effective, thanks! I was thinking too hard!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really enjoy working with PIVOT so here a solution using APPLY.

```
SELECT
    T.id
    , Val
    , COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable AS T
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        (T.C1)
        , (T.C2)
        , (T.C3)
        , (T.C4)
) AS X(Val)
GROUP BY T.Id, X.Val
ORDER BY T.Id, X.val
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample code:

```
            DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Count = '
        SELECT 
        @Query += '( CASE WHEN '+ COLUMN_NAME + ' = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) + ' 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'ID'
        SET @Query = SUBSTRING(@Query, 1, DATALENGTH(@Query) - 2) + ' FROM TEST WHERE ID = 1'
        EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: I was trying the full solution, mean while @hashbrown answered in a simple way!